# New to node.js found a possible PATH variable error

Tags: node.js

Fairly new to node.js and suddenly this error happened, I tried researching it and found out it could be PATH, but I tried adding it and could not find the solution.

```
C:\Windows\system32>node app.js --harmony
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\system32\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why your current working directory is `C:\Windows\system32` but you really shouldn't be in there running Node code. That's for Windows specific system files *only*.

You'll need to change to the directory with `app.js` in it, or you'll need to specify the full path when running Node:

```
node C:\path\to\app.js --harmony
```

Like all command-line tools, the `node` program will look in the current directory unless told otherwise.